# Wordpress: echo a dynamic_sidebar widget inside of a shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a widget into a shortcode that I'm storing in my footer.php file...

```
<?php
echo do_shortcode( '[accordion_full_width title="upcoming events" full_width="yes" background_color="#68676b"]' . 
dynamic_sidebar( 'footer_contents' )
. '[/accordion_full_width]'); ?>
```

...and it renders out the widget first, followed by the shortcode.

If this is a problem with using the dynamic_sidebar function inside of the do_shortcode, I'd think it just wouldn't spit the widget out, but it does. In the wrong place.

Does anybody have anything?

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code in Your Template

```
 <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Name of Widget') ) :      ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```